# Is a propensity-score match necessary if my pre-match covariates are already balanced?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

I planned to run an analysis starting with a dataset of 22,000 records. From this set, I would conduct a match to obtain two balanced groups then look at my outcomes of interest. I was planning to use an SMD of <0.1 as a measure of achieving balance.

However, if my covariates of interest are already balanced (SMD <0.1) prior to running my match, is it still necessary methodologically to run a a match?

Comment: If you are set up to adjust for covariates, the use of propensity scores is questionable.  There are many reasons not to use matching, detailed [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/propensity.html).  There are also many reasons for not doing propensity score analysis as discussed there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary, and in fact potentially harmful to use propensity score to match once balance has been achieved; this is one of the main messages of [King and Nielsen (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1017/pan.2019.11). Instead, you should adjust for prognostically important covariates using regression, which will improve precision and remove any slight remaining imbalances. With such a large sample, it should be simple to build a flexible regression model that adjusts for the covariates completely.